# Aggregate and ToArray function in System.Array not working

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, ienumerable, system.array

I have this two errors:

> 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and no
>   extension method 'Aggregate' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)
>
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object[]>' does not contain
>   a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object[]>' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code:

```
    /*
     * Get all the possible permutations
     */
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> CartesianProduct(params object[][] inputs)
    {
        //ERROR: Function Aggregate is not recognized
        return inputs.Aggregate(
            (IEnumerable<object[]>)new object[][] { new object[0] },
            (soFar, input) =>
                from prevProductItem in soFar
                from item in input
                select prevProductItem.Concat(new object[] { item }).ToArray());
    }

    public void test()
    {
            //Get all the posible permutations between parents values.
            var cartesianProduct = CartesianProduct(parentsValues);
            object[][] producto = cartesianProduct.ToArray();
            //ERROR: Function ToArray is not recognized
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your file. Without this, the C# compiler doesn't know where the find the LINQ extensions you're trying to use.

Comment: In my tests, it does not depend on the version of .Net (except if you go back to a version without LINQ - but 3.5 is fine), only on whether `using System.Linq;` is included. Perhaps you're testing the different versions by cutting and pasting the methods between files with different `using`s? If you can show an [example](http://www.sscce.org/), either the answer will be clear or we can discover some obscure thing/bug about C#.

Answer (score 0):

Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of .cs file.